# VideoPlayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: flutter, video-player

i already used latest version of video_player flutter (video_player: ^0.10.5+1)
but show below warning.

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/pc/Documents/AshishAlagiya/Flutter/Tool/flutter112hotfix5/flutter/.pub-cache/git/plugins-e1e8a04bd104a6a772e6f0e72eaf8615f14c6541/packages/video_player/video_player/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/videoplayer/VideoPlayerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the following to your app/build.gradle

```
  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it solved after adding the permission in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```